# Adding more logic to an elseif

Tags: mysql

I hae this mysql code

```
elseif ( exists(select id from transactions where tel = last_inserted_number && secure_using_payslip IS NULL)) then
    update transactions set secure_using_payslip=last_inserted_message where 
     tel=last_inserted_number;

     elseif(last_inserted_message = 'no')then
      insert into messageout(messagetext, messageto)
        values("you choose not to secure with payslip.", last_inserted_number);

        elseif(last_inserted_message = 'yes')then
      insert into messageout(messagetext, messageto)
        values("you choose to secure with payslip.", last_inserted_number);
```

What it does is in the first `elseif` is that it updates the table transactions with `yes` or `no` to the question `Would you like to secure the loan with a payslip`.

I would like to do something if the answer was `no` and a completely different thing if the answer is `yes`.How would i add that code to the first `elseif`?.

Comment: Can't you put another `if` inside the result of the first `elseif`? E.g. `elseif(exists(...)) then if (last_inserted_message = 'no') then ... else ... `?

Comment: I haven't tried this,`insert into messageout(messagetext, messageto)
        values("you choose not to secure with payslip.", last_inserted_number)  case when last_inserted_message = 'no';`